# Extjs how to represent matrix in extjs

Tags: extjs

Is there any `Extjs` component to represent an editable matrix.

**Something along these lines:**

```
+------------------------------------+
|   name        | bid1 | bid2 | bid3 |
+------------------------------------+
|   supplier A  |                    |
|   supplier B  |                    |
|   supplier c  |                    |
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Like an [editable grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/cell-editing.html)?  Have you looked at all of the [grid samples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/index.html#sample-2)?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a pivot table. Options:

https://market.sencha.com/extensions/mzpivotgrid

or for extjs 3.4† :

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.PivotGrid

† (you can use 3 and 4 at the same time with the compatibility layer) http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sencha.com%2Fforum%2Fshowthread.php%3F127590-Editable-Grid-example&ei=nCspVcHVLoqwuASmqYD4CA&usg=AFQjCNGRoO0qh0It4Q1fcn2h3-JnQ8Fnaw&sig2=XCrVc_jtQ9wAPeTCSyikGw&bvm=bv.90491159,d.c2E). You can edit any entry in grid using editable grid panel.